# Making cpupower changes persistent

Tags: kernel-modules, persistence

I have been fiddling with power management and I can't find a way to make the changes I want persistent. For example, I have set the maximum cpu frequency with this command:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set --max 2GHz
```

but the value goes back to its original value on every reboot. Is there a standard way to make this change persistent? I have read about kernel modules but I don't know how they work... can anyone help me?

Note. My machine is running Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Arch Wiki page on CPU frequency scaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) suggests a couple of different ways to make changes performed in `cpupower` persistent.

- One of those, as you mentioned, is adding a kernel module. But there are other simpler options that should be easier. The simpler is just to enable `cpufreq`'s `systemd` service, as suggested in the Arch Wiki. Just run

`sudo systemctl enable cpupower`

and the service will be started every time you boot up the machine. I am not running in a machine with `systemd` right now, so I cannot perform any tests.

- The second option is to add a `udev` rule. I've tested this one right now and it works perfectly. Just edit the file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-scaling-governor.rules` or similar (create it if it does not exist) and add the following content to it:

`SUBSYSTEM=="module", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="acpi_cpufreq", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 2000000 | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq'"`

This will change the maximum frequency of CPU0 to the value written. In your case, `2000000`, or 2.0 GHz. To do the same for every CPU in your machine, just change the previous command to

`SUBSYSTEM=="module", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="acpi_cpufreq", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 2000000 | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*[0-9]/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq'"`

and this will change the maximum frequency for every CPU in your system.

Answer (score 1):

```
# cat<<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/cpupower.service 
[Unit]
Description=CPU powersave
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cpupower -c all frequency-set --governor powersave  -d 400MHz -u 1000MHz
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemcl enable cpupower
```